# Score update. Change in every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm new to unity and I'm developing a 2d game. I want my game to update the "scoretext" every 5 seconds and I want it to update for +1. But my code is not working. It is updating in like 0.000...1 second (I mean the program doesn't wait 5 seconds to update). How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
public Text scoretext;
public int score;



IEnumerator scoreup()
    {
        score++;
        scoretext.text = score.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }

void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine("scoreup");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Simple use of `InvokeRepeating` code:

```cs
void ScoreUp()
{
    score++;
    scoretext.text = score.ToString();
}
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(ScoreUp), 0f, 5f); // 0=delay, 5f = repeat Time
}
```

---

### Solution 2:

Use an `IEnumerator`:

```cs
IEnumerator ScoreUp(int amount = 1)
{
    while (true)
    {
        score += amount;
        scoretext.text = score.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }

}
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ScoreUp(2));
}
```

Comment: Make sure you write it in the `Start` event, not the `Update`. Otherwise, the timer of each frame will run and your system will be stacked over flow.

Comment: Note that the timer is written at start.